# Python: How to find version number for mpl_toolkits?

Tags: python, pip

I understand how to find the version number of a python package normally. I would usually just import it in python and do `<package name>.__version__`, or run pip freeze and locate the package of interest.

However, this doesn't work with mpl_toolkits. If I do

```
import mpl_toolkits
mpl_toolkits.__version__
```

I get an attribute error. Running pip freeze, the package doesn't appear. Since the import works it must be installed though. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but can't work out what's going on here, so sorry if the question is dumb.

Comment: It's a part of `matplotlib`, so you should check `matplotlib.__version__`

Comment: Thanks! I think what I was after was the version of basemap, and
`from mpl_toolkits import basemap`
`basemap.__version__`
provides this. I thought mpl_toolkits was the package and basemap was just a part of it due to the import structure.